# Web Service (web method) String return type

Tags: java, xml, web-services, return-type

I have a question about best practices. Let's say I have a web method that returns employee id and employee name. Now, since I am new to Web Service, we( client(C#) and I(Java)) agreed upon a return type `List<String>` and String format is `employee id,employee name`. All is well so far. Program runs and it does the job.

Now, the other day, I was having conversation about return type with another developer and she suggested the way I am returning the data is not right instead I should return String in XML format so the typical output may look like (here without formatting),

```
 <root><employee><employeeId>1234</employeeId><employeeName>firstname lastname</employeeName></employee></root>
```

I argued that, in this case, you're returning more than 50% non-data(XML tags) to client which is unnecessary and waste bandwidth and increase overhead. And she argued back that in case of unobvious scenarios like, user does not have permission to access something or there is nothing to return but the error code or something went wrong on server i.e when you need to return something else other than actual data itself, XML string is helpful since you can insert  tag. And it's a valid argument so can somebody with good experience with Web Service shed some light here?

Comment: I would recommend using none of these approaches. For a lighter experience use RESTful services instead, this is, the returning will be a String in JSON format easy to write from producer and interpret in consumer side. More info: [Representational state transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)

Answer (score 0):

Basically when your list is serialized it will be converted to XML although the format would be like:

```
<Value>EmployeeId, EmployeeName</Value>
```

The tags are not actually unneccessary and in fact they are helpful as they preserve the data and it's conctrete data type. I am not fan of returning an XML string as it is prone to error and you may always need to update the value of the string. What I suggest is to return an object containing your result set and an error description property.

```
public class ReturnObject
{
   public List<Employee> list {get; set;}
   public String ErrorDescription {get; set;}
}

public class Employee
{
   public int EmployeeID {get; set;}
   public string EmployeeName {get; set;}
}
```

In here your web service will return a concrete type with additional property 'ErrorDescription' that you can use if you need to return any validation or authentication errors. Use SoapUI to test that serialized return object is XML.